# clear form values and show confirmation message after submission ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I'm a newbie to this level of coding, so I probably shouldn't be trying to move code around, but I'm so close I can't give up on it!
I have a contact form on a website I'm building - a template I bought. I'm not a fan of the form layout, so instead I'm trying to use a form from another website I set up. Both use ajax to send the form, and both - in their original form - have a fade in confirmation message on sending. I have replaced all the code from the new template with the code from the old template, and I can get the form to send the email, but I can't get the email fields to clear after submission, and I can't get the confirmation/error messages to show up.
This is the code I have:
This is my form:

```
<div id="contact-form" class="row">
<div class="large-10 large-centered columns">
<form action="js/sendmail.php" method="post" class="contact-form">  
<input type="hidden" name="type" value="full" />
<p><h5 class="text-white left">Name</h5><br>
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name*" /></p>
<p><h5 class="text-white left">Email</h5>
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="e-mail*" /></p>
<p><h5 class="text-white left">Subject</h5>
<input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="subject*" /></p>
<p><h5 class="text-white left">Message</h5>
<textarea name="message" placeholder="message*" ></textarea></p>
<p><input id="form-button" type="submit" value="Send" /></p>  
</form>
</div>
```

This is my php script:

```
<?php
 /**
  * @package Website_Template
  * @since Website 1.0
  *
  * Script for receiving, validating and sending contact form.
  * Use $config variable to define email address for incoming contact forms.
  */

 // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

 // Configuration
 $config = array
 (
    'title' => 'CC-UK',             // prefix of the contact form message's subject
    'email' => 'my@emailaddress.com' // e-mail address for incoming contact forms
 );

 // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

 /**
  * Return output
  *
  * @param boolean $result
  * @param string $message
  */
 function output($result, $message)
 {
    echo json_encode(array('result' => $result, 'message' => $message));
    exit;
 }

 // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

 // Form type
 $full = isset($_POST['type']) && $_POST['type'] == 'full';

 // Parsing POST data
 foreach (array('name', 'email', 'subject', 'message') as $field) {
    ${$field} = isset($_POST[$field]) ? trim(strip_tags($_POST[$field])) : '';
 }
 if (!$full) {
    $name = $email;
 }

 // Data validation
 if (empty($name) && $full) {
    output(false, 'Please enter your name.');
 } else if (!preg_match('/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)+$/i', $email)) {
    output(false, 'Invalid email address.');
 } else if (strlen($message) < 3) {
    output(false, 'Please write your comment.');
 }

 // Data preparing
 $subject = rtrim("[{$config['title']}] ".trim(str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), ' ', $subject)));
 $option = isset($_POST['option']) ? $_POST['option'] : 'no';
 if ($full) {
    $message .= "\r\n\r\nOption: {$option}\r\n\r\n---\r\n{$name}\r\n{$email}";
 } else {
    $message .= "\r\n\r\n---\r\n{$email}";
 }

 // Send mail
 $result = @mail(
    $config['email'],
    '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?=',
    $message,
    "From: {$name} <{$config['email']}>\r\n".
    "Reply-to: {$email}\r\n".
    "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n".
    "Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\n"
 );
 if ($result) {
    output(true, 'Message sent.');
 } else {
    output(false, 'Error occured. Message couldn\'t be sent.');
 }
```

And this is my js code (in a separate scripts file):

```
    // Contact form
    $('.contact-form').submit(function() {
        if ($('input[type="submit"]', this).prop('disabled')) {
            return false;
        }
        var _this = this;
        $('input[type="submit"]', this).prop('disabled', true);
        $('.message', this).slideUp(300);
        $('.load', this).fadeIn(300);
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            type: 'POST',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            complete: function() {
                $('input[type="submit"]', _this).prop('disabled', false);
                $('.load', _this).fadeOut(300);
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $('.message', _this).removeClass('green orange');
                if (data === null) {
                    $('.message', _this)
                        .text('Unknown error.')
                        .addClass('orange')
                        .slideDown(300);
                } else {
                    $('.message', _this)
                        .text(data.message)
                        .addClass(data.result ? 'green' : 'orange')
                        .slideDown(300);
                    if (data.result) {
                        $('input[type="text"], textarea', _this).val('');
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });

 });
```

So what I can't work out is why this works fine on my original site (form clears on sending, fade in confirmation message appears) but on the site I'm trying to install it on, although the email sends, it won't clear the form and there's no confirmation.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked to see that you're ajax response code is success?  A quick check would be to add an error handler in your ajax like `error: function() { alert("there was an error"); console.log(arguments); } or something similar.